# Can't get my Netgear A6210 USB Wifi Adapter to work on my linux Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, compiling

I am running Ubuntu 18 on a desktop. I dont have a wifi card. however, i have this Netgear A6210 usb wifi adapter. I plugged it in but it is not coming up. i think the computer did not recognize the device.

I tried installing the driver following these instruction i founf online that seems to work for everyone. But i get this error message.

Instruction:

```
git clone https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210

cd Netgear-A6210

make

sudo make install
```

Error message:

```
~/Documents/Netgear-A6210$ make
export DBGFLAGS

*** Building driver with debug messages ***

cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/Makefile

make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/build DBGFLAGS=-DDBG SUBDIRS=/home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux modules

make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o

In file included from ./include/linux/bitmap.h:9:0,
                 from ./include/linux/cpumask.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:11,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:21,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:36,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/include/os/rt_linux.h:14,
                 from /home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/include/rtmp_os.h:30,
                 from /home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/include/rtmp_comm.h:64,
                 from /home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:33:
In function ‘memcpy’,
    inlined from ‘rt_ioctl_iwaplist’ at /home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:549:2:

./include/linux/string.h:340:4: error: call to ‘__read_overflow2’ declared with attribute error: detected read beyond size of object passed as 2nd parameter
    __read_overflow2();

    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/alseny/Documents/Netgear-A6210/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:59: recipe for target 'debug' failed
make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

Answer (score 9):

I suggest that you remove the inoperable file:

```
cd ~/Documents
rm -rf Netgear-A6210
```

Now clone and build a better version:

```
git clone -b port-to-4.15 https://github.com/kaduke/Netgear-A6210.git
cd Netgear-A6210
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot.

Comment: This works fine for me. If you don't want to reboot, just unplug and plug in the usb device again, and then to run `sudo service network-manager restart` to restart the network manager.

Comment: Thank you for posting the better version - works on kali rolling 64

Comment: Update - after testing further this version "kaduke/Netgear-A6210" freezes the network-manager and causes a near halt to restarting the system.  Although the Netgear adapter can be seen in network-manager, any attempts to connect to a access point causes internal wifi driver to shutdown and cannot be restarted and the Netgear-A6210 freezes.

Comment: @LuigiNesbitt Kali is off topic here. You probably need to blacklist the internal device.

Comment: No problems here on Pop-OS 18.10 so far, thankfully, though my "main" Linux is Ubuntu 18.04 and I will be trying it on there soon. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this response as well as the comments, all of them have been most helpful!

Comment: What worked for me was cloning from `https://github.com/Netgear-A6210-linux-driver/Netgear-A6210.git`