# Troubles Installing

Tags: command-line, networking, adapter

I remember using multiple floppies and taking nearly a week with my young geekie son in the early 90s to install Linux, hardware and all.  Off and on used many flavors past two decades or so.

All I am trying to do now is install the Netgear A6210 adapter on this Ubuntu 18.04 Linux install, as it appears not to have installed during the OS install. I clicked for it to install additional hardware, and it found everything else I needed. 
A search on Youtube and Google revealed no help.  Also, since it has been a long time I forgot how to change directories and am looking online for terminal commands.

I have a cable card for ethernet, but no cables in the house for some years now.  Been wireless too long.  Without internet, I have to go back into Winders 7 constantly to research how to do things.

Also, each boot after trying Ubuntu Linux, the clock in Windows 7 is turned back five hours and the Netgear A6210 network adapter is "not found" and must be re-installed in Windows 7, taking fifteen minutes to reconnect to the Internet.  Very annoying.

Any help would be appreciated. I feel very newbie, and am too old to be a newbie again.

Thanks.

Peace,
Zukester

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TroubleShootingGuide which will lead you to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide the most useful section is "Device Recognition and Operation" which will provide clues for searching online, plus allowing us to help you. Netgear A6210 means little; the chipset used within it is key which is provided in the "Device Recognition" bit...  (brand/model internals can change over time)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get my Netgear A6210 USB Wifi Adapter to work on my linux Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033772/cant-get-my-netgear-a6210-usb-wifi-adapter-to-work-on-my-linux-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that NetGear doesn't like Linux haha

I suggest that you remove the inoperable file:

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033772/cant-get-my-netgear-a6210-usb-wifi-adapter-to-work-on-my-linux-ubuntu) question that looks very similar to your situation, I'll copy the answer over for convenience.

```
cd ~/Documents
rm -rf Netgear-A6210
```

Now clone and build a better version:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install git
git clone -b port-to-4.15 https://github.com/kaduke/Netgear-A6210.git
cd Netgear-A6210
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot.