# 20.04.1 LTS not completely booting - need WIFI

Tags: boot, wireless

SUMMARY: After installing an update about 2 weeks ago, 20.04.1 LTS does not completely boot.  I do have the desktop but no WIFI now (doing this in Windows 7). Bringing up a terminal window to try to debug using some of the help threads I read (and wrote down), entering "sudo" and then the advised command, return, there is no prompt for my sudo password.  The terminal display does nothing.  Additional carriage returns only move the cursor further down the terminal window.

BACKGROUND:
I am currently residing at a location which ONLY has WIFI for internet access (so any solutions CAN NOT be with a cable internet connection).  The only means right now for me to access Ubuntu help is with a spare hard drive that has Windows 7 on it.  In W7, I downloaded the 20.04.1 ISO and burnt a DVD with it.  After removing the W7 HD, on another HD, I did a disk wipe of it, booted the 20.04.1 ISO DVD, and installed it to the HD.  This was about 6 weeks ago.

The first time boot Ubuntu ran fine INCLUDING WIFI.  A short time after running, the software update popup said a lot of updates to install which I did.  Again, after rebooting everything worked fine.

I continued to install any updates in the following weeks, with all working fine.  Then, about 2 weeks ago for that update, that is when the problem occured.

At that time, I tried a COMPLETE fresh install of 20.04.1 LTS, but after doing all of the updates right then, again the same problem.  And all of this time since the problem I could not power down the PC by software.  I would have to hold the PC power off button.

I also tried downloading and installing the ISO for 20.10.  Suprisingly this worked fine (including WIFI) for all updates it notified me of.  So I suspect there is something in the last 20.04.1 LTS update I could do that has something missing in it for a complete clean boot, including WIFI running.  I do not want to run 20.10 though, since a lot of the 20.04.1 programs I need to run don't work well in 20.10.

Again, I do not have cable internet access just WIFI, with either W7 or 20.10.  I can boot the 20.10 HD with the 20.04.1 LTS HD running.  So if there is something I can check from 20.10 on the 20.04.1 LTS HD I can do that ("sudo" does work in 20.10).

ADDITIONAL INFO:
20.04.1 LTS
GNOME 3.36.3
winsys X11
Netgear AC1200 WIFI USB 3.0 Adapter Model A6210
Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 chipset

Thanks for any help, since I would prefer using 20.04.1 for my efforts and not W7.

Comment: How is "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 chipset" related? What is your wireless device? This is a long story with unnecessary detail, bit no hint about the hardware.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get my Netgear A6210 USB Wifi Adapter to work on my linux Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033772/cant-get-my-netgear-a6210-usb-wifi-adapter-to-work-on-my-linux-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to get WIFI working again with 20.04.1 LTS. It stopped working about 2 weeks ago with the last update, and I can no longer login in to "sudo" for debugging the problem either. I provided the history of the situation in case it helped with figuring out the problem. The WIFI chipset info in case it was a driver problem.

Please let me know specifically the information you need to know - thanks.